# Proof of ${n \choose k} + {n \choose k + 1}$, not sure on how the steps were done

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

I don't understand how they got from the first step to the second step to the third when they combined the fractions, I don't get how terms on the denominator just disappeared too. Bear with me, my algebra is very rusty.

[image: PROOF]

Comment: Requesting clarification, do you mean you are not sure how $k!(k+1) = (k+1)!$ and $(n-(k+1))!(n-k) = (n-k)!$ (in the denominators) according to the definition of factorial?

Comment: The second line looks a peculiar way of presenting it.  I would have written something like $=\dfrac{n!(k+1)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}+\dfrac{n!(n-k)}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}$ as a natural step of creating a common denominator from the first line and directly leading to the third line.  But the original second line and my alternative are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the first step

$\bigg(\frac{n!}{k!\space(n-k)!}\bigg)$ + $\bigg(\frac{n!}{(k+1)!\space(n-(k+1))!}\bigg)$

Here , notice that

1. (k+1)! = (k+1)k!

And

2. (n-k)!= (n-k)(n-(k+1))!

For the sake of simplicity , let's deal with the leftmost expression first :-

thus the taking the to get a common denominator,  you multiply  the denominator and numerator of

$\bigg(\frac{n!}{k!\space(n-k)!}\bigg)$ by (k+1)

To obtain: $\bigg(\frac{n!\space(k+1)}{k!\space(n-k)!\space(k+1)}\bigg)$

Recall our identity 1.
Thus by simplifying the denominator we get:
$\bigg(\frac{n!\space(k+1)}{(k+1)!\space(n-k)!}\bigg)$

For the right most expression now,

Multiply the numerator and denominator of
$\bigg(\frac{n!}{(k+1)!\space(n-(k+1))!}\bigg)$ by (n-k)

You get:

$\bigg(\frac{n!\space(n-k)}{(k+1)!\space(n-(k+1))\space(n-k)}\bigg)$

Recall our identity 2. And apply it to the denominator.

You obtain:

$\bigg(\frac{n!\space(n-k)}{(k+1)!\space(n-k)!}\bigg)$

See that now both the denominators are the same.

$\bigg(\frac{n!\space(k+1)}{(k+1)!\space(n-k)!}\bigg)$ +$\bigg(\frac{n!\space(n-k)}{(k+1)!\space(n-k)!}\bigg)$

Take the n! in the numerator and the (k+1)!(n-k)! denominator as common and simplify.

You'll be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to "equate the denominators". Notice that
$$\frac{(k+1)!}{k!}=k+1$$
and
$$\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-(k+1))!}=\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k-1)!}=n-k.$$
So we extend the first fraction by $k+1$ and the second fraction by $n-k$ having the common denominator $(k+1)!(n-k)!.$
Meanwhile, numerators become $n!(k+1)$ and $n!(n-k).$
Since denominators are now equal on the second line, we add numerators above a common denominator in the third line getting
$$n!(k+1)+n!(n-k)=n!(k+1+n-k)=n!(1+n)=n!(n+1)=(n+1)!$$
as the numerator in the forth line. Note that in the third and fourth lines the denominator did not changed as value. Also, we don't need outer paranthesis in the third line expression.
Finally, the fourth line is equal to the fifth line by the "definition of combination". That is why in the forth line the denominator is re-arranged.

I think Yuvraj explained better. I just noticed the new answer.